# 3DText - Change Text Through Script - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have read lot of questions on how to change text of a 3DText from script.

Lot of them suggested the following :::

```
GetComponent(TextMesh).text = "blah";
```

But when I try to use this, I get an error  `Expression denotes a`type', where a `variable',`value' or `method group' was expected`

I tried a lot of examples and couldn't really get it to work.

```
TextMesh textMesh;
textMesh = (TextMesh) descriptionObject.transform.GetComponent("Text Mesh");
textMesh.text = "Name : ABC";
```

The above code though Compiles without errors doesn't change the text. Can someone help me out with this? How do I change the TEXT of a 3DText Object.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works !!!!

```
textMesh = (TextMesh) descriptionObject.transform.GetComponent(typeof(TextMesh));
        textMesh.text = "Name : ABC";
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be a prettier solution than one already given(C# script used in example) :

```c#
//define a Textmesh that we want to edit 
public TextMesh tm;

// here in start method (run at instantiating of script) i find component of type
    // TextMesh ( <TextMesh> ) of object named"nameOfTheObject" and reference it
    // via tm variable;
void Start () {
    tm = (TextMesh)GameObject.Find ("nameOfTheObject").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
           // here we change the value of displayed text
            tm.text = "new Text u want to see";
}
```

Or if u want to do it the shortest way possible (syntax wise):

```c#
//keep in mind this requires for the script to be attached to the object u
// are editing (the 3dText);
//same as above, the only difference is the note in the line above as this
// method is run from gameObject.GetComponent....
// gameObject is a variable which would be equivalent of this.GetComp...
// in some other programming languages 

GetComponent<TextMesh>().text ="new Text u want";
```